# R Steamgraph error: "invalid subscript type list"

Tags: r, visualization, stream-graph

I get the following error using the steamgraph package

```
 library(streamgraph)
 streamgraph(data, "Keys" ,"Box.Office", date = 11-11-2011, interactive=TRUE)
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Sample of the data:

```
days;Box.Office;Key

1; 2324234;Lucy

2; 123123;Lucy

3; 898989;Lucy

.....

1; 231231;Interstellar

2; 32423;Interstellar
```

Comment: * could not add the steamgraph tag

Comment: in the future, you're more likely to get pkg author help via github issue filings as I am not actively monitoring `[r] streamgraph` on SO.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, there is a typo in your code: `Keys` should be `Key` and the `interactive` argument is set to `TRUE` by default, you do not need to specify it.

Most likely the problem is that `streamgraph` does not know how to deal with the `days` column, in fact if you change the `days` column with something (numeric or character) that can be converted to `as.Date` it works well.

The example of the [official page](http://hrbrmstr.github.io/streamgraph/#fn9) show that all example do have column (numeric or character) that can be interpreted as valid date, furthermore you can explore the body of the function with just typing `streamgraph` in R and you'll see more closely what it does.

With the provided data, to allow function work you need other informations. Here is an example where I have converted the `days` column to dates. It works well and produce the plot.

```
library(streamgraph)
streamgraph(df, "Key" ,"Box.Office", "days")
```

just use this data:

```
df <- structure(list(days = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1), class = "Date"), 
    Box.Office = c(2324234L, 123123L, 898989L, 231231L, 32423L
    ), Key = c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Interstellar", "Interstellar"
    )), .Names = c("days", "Box.Office", "Key"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr you are the author of the `streamgraph` package! I hope that my answer is exhaustive, feel free to add and/or correct it if I've said something incorrect, I do appreciate that if useful to make me learn!

Comment: @hrbrmstr
Thank you very much for the help :). When using your data I still get an error.
`test`
 `> df <- structure(list(days = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1), class = "Date"),` `Box.Office = c(2324234L, 123123L, 898989L, 231231L, 32423L), Key =` `c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Interstellar", "Interstellar")), .Names = c("days",`
`"Box.Office", "Key"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")`
.
`> streamgraph(df, "Key" ,"Box.Office", "days")`

`Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "arrange"`

Comment: time limit*
I used exactly the same code as you gave me:

`> df <- structure(list(days = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1), class = "Date"), Box.Office = c(2324234L, 123123L, 898989L, 231231L, 32423L), Key = c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Interstellar", "Interstellar")), .Names = c("days", "Box.Office", "Key"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")`


`> streamgraph(df, "Key" ,"Box.Office", "days")`

`Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "arrange"`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you, such a beginner mistake :)